# Using <uses-library> in AndroidManifest file only for specific devices

Tags: java, android, shared-libraries, android-manifest

I have Android application, that will work on the different devices with scanners. And for one device model I need to use their SDK, which requires to add next code into AndroidManifest file.

```
<uses-library
        android:name="com.datalogic.device"
        android:required="true" />
```

The problem is in that, if I will try to run this application on the another device model, program will not compile. Getting next 
[error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UJpG.png) When I'm removing code, which I included above, from Manifest file, everything works good.
So is that possible to write in Java code or in the AndroidManifest file, something that will check device name, and will decide to use uses-library code or not?

Comment: you will have to release multiple APKs if you need different manifests for different devices.

Comment: This is because you're setting `required` to `true`. You can set it to `false` and check at runtime and fail "gracefully" by printing an app error that this device requires support for the device in question, but the user may get annoyed.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the device model by getting the string value of `android.os.Build.MODEL;`, you will get the model number (ex : SM-G928F for Galaxy S6 Edge Plus) and then decide how library to use, but you can't change the manifest at runtime